# save custom view drawing canvas on orientation change

Tags: android, orientation, android-canvas, android-orientation

I have seen countless examples of people trying to save their variables in case the user flips the screen. But I did not find any specific to bitmaps or arraylist of paths successful.

So Ithe idea is I have an drawing app that consist of the main activity with a fragment inside. Within the fragment layout is a custom view class where I implement the drawing via canvas, bitmaps, and arraylist. I have found that the best way to approach is parcelables. I have seen that it isn't a good idea to pass bitmaps through. I don't know how to pass the arraylist of paths through since it takes only general ints, string, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert your List of `Path`s to a List of `Points`.

```
ArrayList<Path>  -> ArrayList<Point>
```

BTW, you should probably store the point locations in percentages instead of pixel values depending on your need. Then, simply recreate your List of `Path`s from the list of `Point`s

Comment: That would be the approach but I am filling a grid not just drawing. Sort of like a pixelated image. I draw a rect and store that in the path arraylist.